# Entity Framework Best Practice (winforms + EF 6.1)

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I am currently updating old winforms code that used datatables to use EF, this is just to keep all new programming and old programming inline but thats not really important.

My issue is as follows:
I have a form which requires 2 tables (below example - not actual tables)

```
Table A:
- Reference [key]
- Description
- Version

Table B:
- Table A Reference [key]
- Test Number [key]
- Description
```

I am querying these tables like so:

```
public TableA GetTableA(string Reference)
{
    TableA query;

    using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
    {
        //Collect current result from db where Reference = TableA.Reference
        query = (from a in db.TableA
                where a.Reference == Reference
                select a).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    return query;
}
```

Then the same again for the other table which is just a list instead of a single record (so just substitute values above with List and query.ToList etc.)

The user can then add / remove / update data across the tables in one form which is fine, but then when it comes to saving back to the db I'm running into my issue as the Models are no longer tracked by my DBContext at this point so I have to do manual checks.

Table A is easy and I just pull the record from the DB where Reference = myModel.Reference then add:

```
db.Entry(oldTableA).CurrentValues.SetValues(TableA);
```

But then for Table B I have to manually check what has been added / deleted by

```
// Count values in current TableB model
int countTableB = tableB.Count();

List<TableB> deletedTableB = (from tb in db.TableB
                              where tb.Reference == Table.Reference
                              && tb.TeNo > countTableB
                              select tb).ToList();

db.TableB.RemoveRange(deletedTableB);

foreach(var item in TableB)
{
    TableB oldTableB = (from tb in db.TableB
                        where tb.Reference == item.Reference
                        && tb.TeNo == item.TeNo
                        select tb).SingleOrDefault();

    if(oldTableB != null)
    {
        db.Entry(oldTableB).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
    }
    else
    {
        db.TableB.Add(item);
    }
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

(Note: the above is also in a using block like original queries as well)

I would like to know if this is completely wrong and I'm just a bit of a tool at understanding the way Entities should be used and if there is a better way to be able to compare and update all records.

My other thought for this was to instead just delete all values from TableB where TableB.Reference = TableA.Reference, then just an AddRange like so:

```
List<TableB> deletedVals = (from tb in db.TableB
                            where tb.Reference == Table.Reference
                            select tb).ToList();

db.TableB.RemoveRange(deletedVals);
db.TableB.AddRange(TableB);

db.SaveChanges();
```

But was overall unsure whether this still fell in good practice / overall speed difference of the 2.

Further to this, they also need to implement a check that will see if something has changes and prompt the user to update (i.e. MessageBox - We have detected something has changed would you like to save?) however they're quite insistent that it only pops up if something is changed, so if the RemoveRange / AddRange query would work for the first question, is there a way I can have something for this as well (if I removed, then added items I think it would always assume there is a change so I would have to instead default to the current code I have just for the check - except without the SaveChanges and the addition of running through a ChangeTracker).

EDIT: Got around the top by adding a boolean that changes whether or not results are found, however this seems a bit of a pain as opposed to setting a "using" block in the controller (or viewmodel), and passing the db context through to the business logic layer, however from what i've read everywhere thats a bit naughty, does this still hold true in this circumstance?